# Realm in IOS: Primary key can't be changed after an object is inserted

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I'm some new in using Realm. I've some code:

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
            [realm transactionWithBlock:^{
                self.object.objectPrimaryKey = someValue;
            }];
```

An exception occures on this string: `self.object.objectPrimaryKey = someValue;` with reason: `'Primary key can't be changed after an object is inserted.'`

```
objectPrimaryKey is a primary key. What can I do to fix it?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys) about primary key, you can set primary key only once.

You can't change key once it's set:
`Override Object.primaryKey() to set the model’s primary key. Declaring a primary key allows objects to be looked up and updated efficiently and enforces uniqueness for each value. Once an object with a primary key is added to a Realm, the primary key cannot be changed.`