# Back button and creating new entry causes app to crash (UUID cannot be amended) Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

When I go back to VC1 (which allows the user to input a title for a book and create an entry in realm including the title and a UUID for that book) from VC2 (using the provided back button as part of the navigation controller not a custom segue) and then create a new book object in Realm (by adding another title to the text field in VC1), the app crashes saying I cannot amend the primary key once set.

I am intending to create a new entry (in theory I could add one, go back, add another etc) rather than try to overwrite an existing entry.

I've read the docs (and even looked at an old project where a similar thing is working) but I can't understand why it isn't just creating a new entry. I looked at the Realm docs (e.g. referenced in this answer [Realm in IOS: Primary key can't be changed after an object is inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51501353/realm-in-ios-primary-key-cant-be-changed-after-an-object-is-inserted))

Code here is VC1 allowing the user to create a new novel (by adding a title into a text field which is earlier in the code)

```
func createNewNovel() {

        let realm = try! Realm()
        novelCreated.novelID = UUID().uuidString
        novelCreated.novelTitle = novelTitleInput.text!
        novelCreated.createdDate = Date()

        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(novelCreated)
                print ("Novel Created Successfully")
            }
        } catch {
            print("error adding novel")
        }
```

Then I prepare to pass the novelID to VC2 :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let novelData = NovelObject()
        novelData.novelID = novelCreated.novelID

        if let destVC = segue.destination as? WriteVC {
        destVC.novelIDPassed = novelData.novelID

        }
    }
```

This works fine and the segue triggers from a button press on VC1. I can also print the ID of the novel in VC2 so that's working fine.

BUT... when I go back from VC2 and input a new title in the text field in VC1 it should create a new NovelObject, not try to update the existing one (which is causing it to crash). You could even theoretically have the same book title twice but they should have a different UUID (which is the primary key)

I must be missing something trivial I suppose but can't work it out!

The novel is created as at the top :

```
class NewNovelVC: UIViewController {

let novelCreated = NovelObject()

@IBOutlet weak var novelTitleInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var createButtonOutlet: UIButton!
```

then it is populated with variables

Comment: When do you create `novelCreated`? It's a live object, so you need to create a new one before setting the `novelID` etc.

Comment: hey thanks for helping - i've added this to the question - its as if when you hit back it remembers what was there before so just tries to recreate the same thing regardless of what title you put in

Comment: That is created when the VC first loads and it's the same object when you hit the back button. You need to create it prior to setting the novelID. Otherwise, you're trying to change the primary key on the existing object. You'll need to change it from `let` to `var`. Actually, you should just put `var novelCreated: NovelObject!` at the top of the file and then `novelCreated = NovelObject()` immediately before setting the `novelID`.

Comment: thanks Don - this worked perfectly and I see the reasoning which is even more helpful!

Comment: @Don is correct. i recommend creating a singleton class for this. This way you wont always be calling the same instance of the object.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to classic issue of same object being in the memory re-instantiated which points to the same value of primary key. Creating a singleton class can be very handy here as well.

Create a service file. This will keep your `RealSwift` initialized on a specific thread as your current block.

**RealService.swift**

```
import RealmSwift

    class RealmService {

        static let uirealm = RealmService()

        private var _initRS = try! Realm()

        var realm: Realm! {
            return _initRS
        }
    }
```

**Novel.swift** :

```
import RealmSwift

    class Novel : Object {

        @objc dynamic var uid : String? = nil
        @objc dynamic var title: String? = nil

        override static func primaryKey() -> String {
            return "uid"
        }

    }

    extension Novel {

        func writeToRealm(){
            try? RealmService.uirealm.realm.write {
                print("Creating the Novel Object")
                RealmService.uirealm.realm.add(self, update: true)
            }
        }

        func DeleteFromRealm(object: Results<Novel>){
            try? RealmService.uirealm.realm.write {
                print("Deleting the Novel Object")
                RealmService.uirealm.realm.delete(object)
            }
        }

    }
```

and just implement as @Don mentioned, write in the block where you are setting the title.

```
   var novel: Novel! // Declare this in above in the class.

    novel = Novel()
    novel.title = title
    novel.uid = uid
    novel.writeToRealm()
```

Hope that helped.